# Mac stuck in partial Grayscale mode

Tags: finder, macos, ui

I was bored one day an thought it would be cool to follow this tutorial to make my Finder windows look like Retro Mac OS Finder http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/20/simplify-os-x-finder-retro-mac-os-classic-style/.

I thought it would add to the effect if I made my Mac Grayscale by going into System Preferences > Accessibility > Display > Use Grayscale.

And then, as usual, I got annoyed by the theme and changed everything back.

Everything switched back nicely including grayscale. But then I noticed that on login, the color of files in Finder Windows and on the Desktop, when selected, was gray, the same color when in Grayscale.  See pictures.

Grayscale Unchecked:

[image: Grayscale Unchecked]

Grayscale Checked:

[image: Grayscale Checked]

What it should be

[image: What it should be]

**What I've tried so far:**
- Restart

- Reset SMC
- Reset NVRAM
- Disk Utility First Aid (Permission Errors in Plists)
- Safe Mode
- Deleted Bunch of Plists in ~/Library/Preferences

**Other Info**

I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

Also, when I change any of the following options it fixes the problem until next login:

- Accessibility > Display > Use grayscale
- Accessibility > Display > Increase contrast
- Accessibility > Display > Invert Colors
- General > Appearance

**My Question:** How do I completely stop grayscale so that it remains *fixed* even after a restart?

Comment: Check your selection color and color mode (Blue/Graphite) in General preferences.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work.

Comment: Well, it half-worked. It looks like a permissions issue—I had a very similar problem. Have a look at [this Apple Support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538).

Comment: Disk Utility First Aid won't help with home folder permissions (unless you used `diskutil resetpermissions` in Terminal).